# How the user with reputation <100 may get the "Custodian" badge?

Tags: support, review, suggested-edits, badges

Looking at one of the user's profiles, I observed that the user with current reputation 1 has the "Custodian" badge awarded for reviewing Suggested Edits. Now, https://math.stackexchange.com/review says that one needs "at least 2k reputation to review Suggested Edits". However, the history of this user's reputation shows that it never went above 2k during the lifetime of the account (actually, the user joined MSE this year and it was less than 100 at any time). How then this was possible? Was there a bug occasionally allowing users with any reputation to review suggested edits?

Comment: Alternate: when you are suspended, your reputation is temporarily set to 1, but your badges are still there.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The description of the [custodian badge](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/help/badges/85/custodian) says:

> Completed at least one [review](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/review) task. This badge is awarded once per review type.

Whenever a suggested edit is made, the owner of the post receives the notification about the edit and he is asked to review it (even if he has reputation lower then 2k+) and his vote is binding, see: [How do suggested edits work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76251/how-do-suggested-edits-work) and [What happen if other users make edit on someone's answer?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/179257/what-happen-if-other-users-make-edit-on-someones-answer/)

In this way, user with any rep can get custodian badge for reviewing a suggested edit.

Comment: Thanks, this makes sense. I did not know that the user will be asked to review edits to her/his post, since nobody has edited my posts yet ;)

Comment: I guess you only get the badge if you review the suggested edit soon enough after it is suggested (=before other users approve or reject the edit), but I am not entirely sure about this. Anyway, this is the way I've obtained this badge on [some other SE sites](http://biology.stackexchange.com/help/badges/83/custodian?userid=3956), where I have low reputation.

Answer (score 4):

People with less than 2k reputation can still review First Posts and Late Answers I believe. (If I press "Review", those two aren't grayed out)

Also, as of this post I do not have 2k reputation and I have the Custodian badge as well.

Comment: Thanks. I knew that and wouldn't be asking this question otherwise - but clicking on the user's badge, I can check that it is awarded for reviewing Suggested Edits, not for First Posts or Late Answers. I have Custodian badge as well, and it for reviewing First Posts, and I do not have 2k. Martin's explanation makes sense, since it says that that the user may review suggested edits to his/her own posts.