# how to earn the 'Custodian' badge?

Tags: discussion, badges, badge-tracking

I was trying to earn a ['Custodian' badge](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/badges/227/custodian)? The description for the badge tells:

> Completed at least one [review](https://math.stackexchange.com/review) task. This badge is awarded once per review type.

What does it mean exactly? Thanks in advance....

Comment: Some basic info about reviews can be found in [review tag-info](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/tags/review/info). You can access some review queues [starting with 500 reputation](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/access-review-queues) and some other queues only at higher reputation. Still, low rep user might get this badge if somebody makes a suggested edit on their post, see here: [How the user with reputation <100 may get the “Custodian” badge?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/10522)

Answer (score 3):

To earn the custodian badge you need to review one suggested edit. Basically someone suggests a edit to a question to improve it but it has to be checked first by someone else to make sure it is a suitable edit and this is what the reviewer does. But in order to review suggested edits you need at least 2k reputation first (Unless someone edits your posted question and you review it, you can get the badge this way but you have to be quick and do it before another reviewer does ). You could try earning the Editor badge first if you haven't yet, basically you have to edit a question, this could be correcting grammar or editing format etc. Hope this helped!